# Adding animate.css on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So my `p` tag starts as hidden and on hover shows visible. But can anyone help me use `animate.css` to use the slide in effect on the p tag when I hover?

```css
#div:hover{
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   justify-content: center;
}
h2{
  margin-top: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
p{
  visibility: visible;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <div class="div">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `animation-name` of `slideInUp` (predefined in [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)) on your `<p>` tag like:

```
#div:hover p {
  animation-name: slideInUp; // Predefined in animate.css
}
```

You don't even need to use javascript also. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
#div { 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#div:hover {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
#div:hover p {
   animation-name: slideInUp;
}
h2{
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
p{
  visibility: visible;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="div" class="animated">
   <div class="div">
       <h2>Header</h2>
       <p class="animated">Para</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: your example does not work when i press button "Run code snippet"

Comment: @Chris Try now. You need to hover and be patient.

Comment: seems nice. but why not using css3 transition instead of jQuery?

Comment: @Chris Michael Hands has asked it to apply the animate.css on hovering. That's why I just passed the animate.css class via JS. No doubt it can be handled in CSS also but it's kind of re-writing animate.css's code again into your custom CSS. Don't you agree?

Comment: yeah. i think to help someone right you should not only handle the symptoms instead of the cause.

Comment: @Chris You can also achieve this using CSS as well. CSS only method.

Comment: thanks a bunch! sorry for the delay.. been away from the computer for a little while. your code worked a treat for me. i knew this was a simple problem and it really got to me all day, big relief now it is done haha! much appreciated

Comment: @MichaelHands It can be done with CSS, then why use javascript?

Comment: @SauravRastogi sorry mate its a learning curve for me xD maybe ill try it with css also.. thanks for the help

Comment: @MichaelHands No issues. But it's just better to know.

Comment: @SauravRastogi tried this out and it works a dream also a lot smoother. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @MichaelHands It's my pleasure! I'm happy that you tried this out.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/g19ej4bd/

```js
$('#div').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('p').slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find('p').slideUp();
});
```

```css
#div:hover{
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   justify-content: center;
}

h2{
  margin-top: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

p{
  visibility: visible;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
   <div class="div">
       <h2>Header</h2>
       <p>dasdas</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please check the `jsfiddle` as the code isn't working in `stackoverflow` snippet.

I've used `jQuery` methods such as `hover`, `mouseleave`, `slideDown` & `slideUp`.

You can control the speed of `slideDown` & `slideUp` by passing parameters.

> **Reference Document:** 
>   
> `slideDown`: http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/ 
>   
> `slideUp` : http://api.jquery.com/slideup/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use any javascript fot this. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeKMRq

see how easy it is to apply effects with css. just apply any value like `height` to you element and a `transtion` for `height`.

then let the `height` change on hovering over the parent container.

nicer and smoother.

Comment: Its better to use `animation-name`. Don't you think? Checkout my answer.